Riverpod not rebuiilding the consumerstaful widget and i am using hive
I am new to riverpod and flutter(go easy on me) and I am trying make this directory kinda thing where I will store my note. So, I made a function to test if my main function would rebuild on when a folder is added to hive and to my surprise it didn't.
here is my provider code:
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/adapters.dart';

import '../models/folder.dart';
import '../models/note.dart';

final folderNotifierProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<FolderNotifier, Box<Folder>>((ref) {
  return FolderNotifier();
});
class FolderNotifier extends StateNotifier<Box<Folder>> {
  late List<Folder> navigationStack = [];
  Folder? currentFolder;



  FolderNotifier() : super(Hive.box<Folder>('folders')) {
    Hive.box<Folder>('folders').listenable().addListener(() {
      state = Hive.box<Folder>('folders');
      print('Changes has been made');
    });
  }


  void navigateToFolder(Folder folder) {
    navigationStack.add(currentFolder!);
    currentFolder = folder;
    state = state;

  }
  void navigateBack() {
    if (navigationStack.isNotEmpty) {
      currentFolder = navigationStack.removeLast();
    }
  }



  Future<void> initializeRootFolder() async {
    final folderBox = Hive.box<Folder>('folders');
    Folder rootFolder;

    if (folderBox.isEmpty) {
      rootFolder = Folder(name: 'Notes');
      await folderBox.add(rootFolder);
    } else {
      rootFolder =
          folderBox.values.firstWhere((folder) => folder.name == 'Notes');
    }
    currentFolder = rootFolder;

  }

  List<Note> filterNotes() {
    return currentFolder?.notes?.cast<Note>() ?? [];
  }

  List<Folder> filterSubfolders() {
    return currentFolder?.subfolders?.cast<Folder>() ?? [];
  }



  Future<void> createSubfolder(Folder parentFolder, String name) async {
   final folderBox = Hive.box<Folder>('folders');
    final subfolder = Folder(name: name);
    await folderBox.add(subfolder);
    parentFolder.subfolders ??= HiveList(folderBox);
    parentFolder.subfolders!.add(subfolder);
    await parentFolder.save();



  }

  Future<void> updateFolder(Folder folder, {String? name}) async {
    folder.name = name ?? folder.name;
    await folder.save();
  }


}

and here is my screen:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:nb_utils/nb_utils.dart';
import '../colors/AppColors.dart';
import '../providers/drawerProvider.dart';
import '../providers/provider.dart';

class Notes extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const Notes({super.key});

  @override
  _NotesState createState() => _NotesState();



}

class _NotesState extends ConsumerState<Notes> {


  final TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _subfolderController = TextEditingController();


  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ref.read(folderNotifierProvider.notifier).initializeRootFolder();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var folders = ref.watch(folderNotifierProvider.notifier);
    var subfolders = ref.watch(folderNotifierProvider.notifier).filterSubfolders();
    var notes = ref.watch(folderNotifierProvider.notifier).filterNotes();

    if (folders.currentFolder == null) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
    }


      return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            scrolledUnderElevation: 0,
            leading: IconButton(
                icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  "assets/images/notes/Menu.svg",
                  height: 24,
                  width: 24,
                  color: AppColors.primaryTextColor,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  ref.read(drawerManagerProvider).openDrawer();
                }).paddingLeft(6),
            actions: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  color: AppColors.secondaryColor,
                ),
                height: 30,
                width: 165,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SvgPicture.asset(
                      "assets/images/notes/crown.svg",
                      height: 16,
                      width: 16,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 6),
                    Text(
                      'Upgrade to premium',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 12,
                          ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ).paddingRight(24),
            ],
            backgroundColor: AppColors.backgroundColor,
            elevation: 0,
          ),
          body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              4.height,
              SizedBox(
                height: 38,
                child: TextField(
                  onTapOutside: (focus) {
                    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                  },
                  enabled: false,
                  controller: _searchController,
                  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall!.copyWith(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: AppColors.primaryTextColor,
                  ),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Search",
                    hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall!.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      color: AppColors.borderColor,
                    ),
                    prefixIcon: UnconstrainedBox(
                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                        "assets/images/notes/search.svg",
                        height: 16,
                        width: 16,
                        color: AppColors.borderColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        strokeAlign: BorderSide.strokeAlignOutside,
                        color: AppColors.primaryColor,
                        width: 1,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        strokeAlign: BorderSide.strokeAlignOutside,
                        color: Color(0xffEAEAEA),
                        width: 0.5,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Color(0xffEAEAEA),
                        width: 0.5,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              24.height,
              if (folders.currentFolder!.name != 'Notes')
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    folders.navigateBack();
                    setState(() {

                    });
                  },
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      SvgPicture.asset(
                        "assets/images/notes/back.svg",
                        height: 22,
                        width: 22,
                        color: AppColors.primaryTextColor,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 4),
                      Text(
                        folders.currentFolder!.name,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
                          fontSize: 18,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              if (folders.currentFolder!.name == 'Notes')
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Text(
                        folders.currentFolder!.name,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
                          fontSize: 18,
                        ),
                      ),

                          ),
                  ],
                ),
              16.height,
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  reverse: false,
                  itemCount: subfolders.length + notes.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    if (index < subfolders.length) {
                      final subfolder = subfolders[index];
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: (){
                          folders.navigateToFolder(subfolder);

                        },
                        child: Container(
                          height: 48,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: AppColors.borderColor,
                              width: 0.5,
                            ),
                          ),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              SvgPicture.asset(
                                'assets/images/notes/folder.svg',
                                height: 24,
                                width: 24,
                                color: AppColors.borderColor,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 12),
                              Expanded(
                                child: Text(
                                  subfolder.name,
                                  style: Theme.of(context)
                                      .textTheme
                                      .bodySmall!
                                      .copyWith(
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    letterSpacing: 0.4,
                                    color:AppColors.primaryTextColor,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              GestureDetector(
                                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                  'assets/images/notes/moreV.svg',
                                  height: 16,
                                  width: 16,
                                  color: AppColors.primaryTextColor,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ).paddingOnly(bottom: 16);
                    } else {
                      final note = notes[index - subfolders.length];
                      final formattedDate =
                      DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm').format(note.createdAt);
                      return GestureDetector(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: AppColors.borderColor,
                              width: 0.5,
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Text(
                                      note.title,
                                      style: Theme.of(context)
                                          .textTheme
                                          .bodyMedium!
                                          .copyWith(
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                        color: AppColors.primaryTextColor,
                                      ),
                                      maxLines: 1,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    ).paddingRight(24),
                                  ),
                                  GestureDetector(
                                    child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                      'assets/images/notes/moreH.svg',
                                      height: 16,
                                      width: 16,
                                      color: AppColors.primaryTextColor,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                              4.height,
                              Text(
                                note.content.trim(),
                                style: Theme.of(context)
                                    .textTheme
                                    .bodySmall!
                                    .copyWith(
                                  fontSize: 13,
                                  height: 1.4,
                                  color: AppColors.secondaryTextColor,
                                ),
                                maxLines: 4,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ).paddingOnly(
                              left: 12, right: 12, top: 12, bottom: 12),
                        ).paddingBottom(16),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ).paddingOnly(left: 24, right: 24),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showAddSubfolderBottomSheet();
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
    );
  }


  void showAddSubfolderBottomSheet() {
    final folders = ref.read(folderNotifierProvider.notifier);
    showModalBottomSheet(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      builder: (context) {
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom, // Add this line
            left: 24.0,
            right: 24.0,
            top: 24.0,
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text('Add Folder To ${folders.currentFolder!.name}',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                    fontSize: 18,
                  )),
              16.height,
              SizedBox(
                height: 48,
                child: TextField(
                  onTapOutside: (focus) {},
                  controller: _subfolderController,
                  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall!.copyWith(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: AppColors.primaryTextColor,
                  ),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Name your folder",
                    hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall!.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      color: Color(0xff98A2B3),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        strokeAlign: BorderSide.strokeAlignOutside,
                        color: AppColors.primaryColor,
                        width: 1,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        strokeAlign: BorderSide.strokeAlignOutside,
                        color: AppColors.primaryTextColor.withOpacity(0.6),
                        width: 0.5,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: AppColors.primaryTextColor.withOpacity(0.6),
                        width: 0.5,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 24),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        _subfolderController.clear();
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'Cancel',
                              style: Theme.of(context)
                                  .textTheme
                                  .bodyMedium!
                                  .copyWith(
                                fontSize: 12,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                          border: Border.all(
                            strokeAlign: BorderSide.strokeAlignInside,
                            color: AppColors.borderColor,
                            width: 0.5,
                          ),
                        ),
                        height: 44,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  8.width,
                  Expanded(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        if (_subfolderController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                          ref.watch(folderNotifierProvider.notifier).createSubfolder(
                            folders.currentFolder!,
                            _subfolderController.text,
                          );
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          _subfolderController.clear();
                        } else {}
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: AppColors.primaryColor,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                        ),
                        height: 44,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'Save',
                              style: Theme.of(context)
                                  .textTheme
                                  .bodyMedium!
                                  .copyWith(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ).paddingOnly(bottom: 24),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

}

I think whenever there is change in the hive box the screen should rebuild but it does not and when I use set state it works. Help a brother out..

Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).
